# non greedy regex still too greedy for xml start and open tags

Tags: xml, regex, replace

First of all, I understand that regex isn't suitable for parsing xml and I should really be using an xml parser instead. Perhaps my question is a good example of why this is true.

Having said that, what I need to do is only a one-time search and replace over some XML files. Plus I am relatively new to regex so I wish to understand regex better and also WHY it is a bad idea for XML.

I have the following XML (original file has no spacing between tags!):

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>Doesn't matter what is here</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <tag2>Anything can <b>go<b> here</tag2>
    <tag3>Hi there</tag3>
</tag1>
```

I need to split the "Hi there" inside the tag3 into two parts that are both enclosed in a tag1 and have the same tag2 if it is present, i.e.:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>Doesn't matter what is here</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <tag2>Anything can <b>go<b> here</tag2>
    <tag3>Hi</tag3>
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <tag2>Anything can <b>go<b> here</tag2>
    <tag3>there</tag3>
</tag1>
```

My initial idea was to use an optional group for tag2 with a non greedy quantifier as follows:

```
<tag1>(<tag2>.*?</tag2>)?<tag3>Hi there</tag3></tag1>
```

and replace with (Java syntax)

```
<tag1>$1<tag3>Hi</tag3></tag1><tag1>$1<tag3>there</tag3></tag1>
```

However the .*? is still too greedy; it matches from the first opening of tag1 to the last closing of tag1. What is the proper regex way to do this? Or is this a hard problem for regex? Is this one of the reasons why using regex for XML is such a bad idea?

I found that using an atomic group does exactly what I want:

```
<tag1>(?>(<tag2>.*?</tag2>))?<tag3>Hi there</tag3></tag1>
```

However I don't really understand why this is so. Why does this work and is this reliable enough?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I try to explain you the regex behaviour:

### 1. Matching behaviour of the first Regex

`<tag1>(<tag2>.*?</tag2>)?<tag3>Hi there</tag3></tag1>`

The pattern starts matching with `<tag1>` then there is a `<tag2>` this is also matched, then it matches with the `.*?` till the first `</tag2>`. Fine, but then the pattern requires a `<tag3>` to follow, there is no, so the regex does backtrack and matches the first `</tag2>` with the `.*?`, then the `.*?` matches anything till the next `</tag2>`. There it finds a following `<tag3>` and can finish successfully.

### 2. Matching behaviour of the atomic group version

`<tag1>(?>(<tag2>.*?</tag2>))?<tag3>Hi there</tag3></tag1>`

The pattern starts matching with `<tag1>` then there is a `<tag2>` this is also matched, then it matches with the `.*?` till the first `</tag2>`.

*Till this point the behaviour is exactly the same than the first regex.*

But now there is no `<tag3>` following, **but the atomic group prevents backtracking**, so the regex fails.

It starts again at the second `<tag1>` where it is successful.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured out 1 by myself and now I also understand 2. I did learn a lesson of using a proper XML parser next time I have to do stuff like this.